# How to extract JSON string from a longer mixed string in a shell script

Tags: json, shell, awk, sed

Given the following string:

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:3264873466873:secret:foo/bar 1564681234.974 foo/bar {"username":"admin","password":"admin123","secret_key":"KASJDFJHAKHFKAHASDF"} 4e397333-3797-4f0b-ad7e-8c1cc0ed041c VERSIONSTAGES AWSCURRENT
```

Within a shell script, how do you extract just the JSON portion to end up like this:

```
{"username":"admin","password":"admin123","secret_key":"KASJDFJHAKHFKAHASDF"}
```

I was able to do it using two sed commands:

```
echo $longString | sed 's/^.*{/{/' | sed 's/}.*$/}/'
```

but was wondering if there is a way to do it using only one command.

Comment: `grep -o '{.*}'` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract continuous part of the input, you can use `grep` with its `-o` option (if supported on your system). It tells grep to only output the matching part.

```
grep -o '{.*}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For extracting columns, use `awk`:

```
echo $longString | awk '{print $4}'
```

Or `cut`:

```
echo $longString | cut -f 4 -d ' '
```

Beware if you have spaces in your JSON data. You might be better off using `jq` to process the results of `aws secretsmanager list-secrets` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
echo $longString | sed -n 's|.*\({.*}\).*|\1|p'
```

to match and print the desired pattern

Answer (score 0):

you can just join the sed commands to a single command
`sed 's/^.*{/{/;s/}.*$/}/'`

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do. I will handle if there are any space in the string.

```
echo $string | awk -F"[{}]" '{print $2}'
"username":"admin","password":"admin123","secret_key":"KASJDFJHAKHFKAHASDF"
```